# Importing registry (.reg) files fails

Tags: powershell, import, registry, windows-server-2012

I'm having trouble importing .reg files on Windows Server 2012. The script works on Server 2008, works when typed at a PowerShell prompt, and works when run by "double-click" on a Server 2012 instance.

The script unzips a file containing .reg files, then imports them into the registry.

```
Write-Output "Unzipping AUX Package"
Unzip-File -File "$DOWNLOAD_DIR\$S3_AUX_PACKAGE" -Destination $destinationFolder
Write-Output "Done unzipping AUX Package"

# Import registry files in the AUX archive package
$registryFiles = Get-ChildItem $destinationFolder | where {$_.extension -eq ".reg"}
$registryFiles = $registryfiles | % {$_.Name}

foreach ($regfile in $registryfiles) { 
        move "$destinationFolder\$regfile" "$DOWNLOAD_DIR"
        $cmd = "regedit /s `"$DOWNLOAD_DIR\$regfile`" " 
        Write-Output "$cmd"
        invoke-expression $cmd
}
```

I can see the the correct parameters and file names appear from the Write-Output entries:

```
Unzipping AUX Package
09:30:08: Done unzipping AUX Package
09:30:09: regedit /s "c:\\downloads\ControlSet001-110-64.reg"
09:30:11: regedit /s "c:\\downloads\CurrentControlSet110-64.reg"
09:30:11: regedit /s "c:\\downloads\HKCU110-64.reg"
09:30:11: regedit /s "c:\\downloads\HKLM110-64.reg"
```

But it only seems to be importing the first two .reg files - both the ControlSet files. The other two "HKCU" and "HKLM" don't import at all.

These are the paths these REG files are trying to write to:

**ControlSet001-110-64.reg** - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\AdminService11.0`

**CurrentControlSet110-64.reg** - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AdminService11.0`

**HKCU110-64.reg** - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\PSC`

**HKLM110-64.reg** - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PSC`

In another script, I'm able to import REG files to write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\` which is weird since I'm unable to write to it's parent node `SOFTWARE`.

I get the same result with `regedit /s` or `reg import`.

How can I investigate this issue? Any pointers? Can I debug individual PowerShell lines - maybe verbose output? Does PowerShell have an equivalent for importing registry files? Please help!

Comment: How do you execute the script on the remote server ? do you use jobs or scheduled tasks ?

Comment: I would run [SysInternals' ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) on the 2012 server, then run the PowerShell script. It will tell you what registry keys are accessed and if the result is ACCESS_DENIED, and what user account was trying. Or it will show you that the script doesn't even try to access these registry keys. Could it be that your remote command can't get to HKEY_CURRENT_USER because it's running as some system user without a real profile, and after that fails it doesn't try the HKLM110-64 file?

Comment: @Kayasax, This script is run via RightScale - a third party to manage various clouds. In this case, AWS instances. The script is run when the instance is booting up.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler  Thanks. I'll try ProcMon and see what is says. It surely looks like HKCU is a culprit, but the script continues to execute the other .REG files even after HKCU as seen from another script that imports similar .REG files (mentioned that in the OP towards the end).

The script works on Win2008 so I suspect it has to do with something that has change on Win2012.

Comment: @urover You say it works on 2008 but you don't say 2008 R2. Is it possible that they are 32bit 2008 servers, and that RightScale is a 32 bit program? So when you run it on 2008 it works. When you run the import on 2012 directly using native tools it works. When you run it on 2012 using RightScale, 2012 is redirecting the writes into `Wow6432Node`? You don't say how it fails - does it error, or does it complete but the keys aren't where you expect?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clear. The script works on Windows 2008 R2. So, yes 64bit OS. 

When running on Win2012 via RightScale, HKLM REG files that are meant for WOW6432Node import just fine-same script different scenario - just assume it's a different script to keep from getting confused.

Only problem is importing REG files into HKLM itself and HKCU.

However, with Ansgar's solution I seem to be able to get HKLM to import. But, HKCU is one that won't import in any of my scripts for Windows 2012. I might need to read up on how user privileges changed for Win2012.Your insights will be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you making things so complicated? The `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet returns `FileInfo` objects, which have a property `FullName` that has the full path to the item, in this case your `.reg` files.

This should work:

```
Write-Output "Unzipping AUX Package"
Unzip-File -File "$DOWNLOAD_DIR\$S3_AUX_PACKAGE" -Destination $destinationFolder
Write-Output "Done unzipping AUX Package"

Get-ChildItem $destinationFolder | ? { $_.Extension -eq '.reg' } | % {
  & reg import $_.FullName
}
```

Note that you need to run this "as Administrator" to be able to write to HKLM.

Comment: Just curious, why are you using the pipleine to filter the file extension, instead of `Get-ChildItem $destinationFolder -Filter "*.reg"` or `Get-ChildItem "$destinationFolder\*.reg"` ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler No particular reason. I just copied most of the OP's code.

Comment: Thank you. I can now see HKLM in the registry now. HKCU continues to evade the import. The script is run with elevated privileges via RightScale (third party cloud management). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @urover Perhaps the script is being run in the context of a different user? In that case HKCU for the script would be different from what you expect. Logging the import with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) might provide more information.

Comment: Thanks to AnsgarWiechers and @TessellatingHeckler for their ProcMon suggestion. I looked at what the script was doing and noticed it was importing the HKCU file, not into HKCU but into HKU. The script's running as SYSTEM user (according to ProcMon) so this is where those registry entries go to, as per my reading about the Windows registry.

I also noticed that this is exactly what happens even on our Windows 2008 R2 machines for the same registry import operation, so I assume this is acceptable behavior for whoever designed it in the company I work for.

Comment: I have had similar issues with HKCU-intended reg hive imports landing in the (registry) "Default" user hive.  What I learned is that you need to utilize "user impersonation" within a custom action of an MSI to essentially accomplish a "RunAs" for the process that executes the import.  Perhaps this "RightScale" tool, when elevated, has a mechanism in place to "RunAs" a different user than SYSTEM; and this will be needed in order to get the import to land in the desired HKCU hive.